# Looping until cell is empty

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

I have my macro written but now I need it to run in a loop until cell I2 is empty.

Can anyone help with this?

```
Sheets("Value Imported Data").Select
Range("I2:Q2").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Good data").Select
Range("I1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

Sheets("Value Imported Data").Select
ActiveCell.Resize(40, 9).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

I assumed it would be something like this but it does not work at all

```
Sub CandidatesInfo()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
Sheets("Value Imported Data").Select

    Set r = Range("I2")

    For Each Cell In r
    If r.Notempty Then


        Range("I2:Q2").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Good data").Select
        Range("I1").Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False

        Sheets("Value Imported Data").Select
        ActiveCell.Resize(40, 9).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Basically what I want to do is if I2 is empty do nothing but if it is not empty copy I2 to Q2 into another sheet and once copied go back in the sheet where the information was copied and delete the next 40 information down and 9 to the right and start over again. As I said the top macro works perfectly, now it is just a matter of starting over and over until I2 is empty.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you very much

Comment: Because the range "r" is only one cell "I2", you are looping throw one cell. so your code will run one time only. And you don't need to set range("I2") in r to check if it is empty, only write : if range("I2").value <> "" then ...  And Notempty is not a propriety of a range

Comment: To loop until I2 is empty use "While" : While Range("I2") <> "" .... wend

Comment: Thanks!! this works great, except it takes a while even when I add a macro to run everything fast... If there is another solution to run faster, I'm all ears. But for now it will do :-) Thanks

Comment: Any ideas to have the macro run faster. I think the WHILE ... WEND is making the macros really slow. I did add all the normal macro to have the macros runs faster and still it is slow. Thank you for helping.

Comment: I think it is slow because you are using a lot of "Select" and "Selection" in your code. You can do better by using "set" objects, for example : set rng=Sheets("Value Imported Data").Range("I2:Q2"). Set it one time before the while loop, so you have not to select it every loop.